# I have no idea whats wrong jquery maybe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, 3d, three.js

I have no idea whats wrong can any one help me?
when I try to load it up on chrome it is just white screen and the code use to be in its own file and it will be when i find out whats wrong it just loads a white page i am trying to make a cube load with help from jquery and three.js

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>THREE</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.js"></script>

    <style>
        body{
            margins:0;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){}

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, .1, 500);
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

        renderer.setColor(0xdddddd);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        var axis = new THREE.AxisHelper(10);
        scene.add(axis);

        var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(50, 5);
        var color = new Color("rgb(255, 0, 0)");
        grid.setColors(color, 0x000000);

        //scene.add(grid);

        var cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5);
        var cubeMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xdddddd, wireframe:true});
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, cubeMat);


        cube.position.x = 0;
        cube.position.y = 0;
        cube.position.z = 0;
        scene.add(cube);

        camera.position.x = 40;
        camera.position.y = 40;
        camera.position.z = 40;

        camera.lookAt(scene.position);
        $("#container").append(renderer.domElement);
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
    });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *$(document).ready(function(){}* Would be a problem, or is it a typo?

Comment: that's a typo but i changed it and still didn't work.

Comment: Line with issue: $(document).ready(function(){}.   Wrong braces in here. It should be $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: what does the console say

Comment: the console says
THREE.WebGLRenderer 71
Uncaught TypeError: renderer.setColor is not a function

Comment: `var color = new Color("rgb(255, 0, 0)");` should be `THREE.Color`

Comment: I would look at an example http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_cube and compare with your code

Comment: There is no method `renderer.setColor`, so I removed that. Also it should be `var color = new THREE.Color("rgb(255,0,0");` not `var color = new Color("rgb(255,0,0");` then you at least get something. These are fairly easy to find errors if you hit f12 and look at the console

Comment: OK that kinda worked it added every thing but the cube I think I got it from now I totally forgot about the console thanks for everything I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the closing bracket from this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
```

Remove this line, setColor doesn't seem to be a method for THREE.WebGLRenderer:

```
    renderer.setColor(0xdddddd);
```

Change:

```
     var color = new Color("rgb(255, 0, 0)");
```

to:

```
     var color = new THREE.Color("rgb(255, 0, 0)");
```

Comment: I changed 
    renderer.setColor(0x000000);
to
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
and that worked as well

Comment: Cool, I'm not familiar with the Three Library but the above changes worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you immediately opened and closed your `$(document).ready(function(){}`. So the right bracket needs to be deleted `$(document).ready(function(){}` so the entire script is contained in it and you have the appropriate closing tag at the bottom.  I don't have three.js, but I think the following should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>THREE</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.js"></script>

    <style>
        body{
            margins:0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, .1, 500);
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

        renderer.setColor(0xdddddd);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        var axis = new THREE.AxisHelper(10);
        scene.add(axis);

        var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(50, 5);
        var color = new Color("rgb(255, 0, 0)");
        grid.setColors(color, 0x000000);

        //scene.add(grid);

        var cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5);
        var cubeMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xdddddd, wireframe:true});
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, cubeMat);


        cube.position.x = 0;
        cube.position.y = 0;
        cube.position.z = 0;
        scene.add(cube);

        camera.position.x = 40;
        camera.position.y = 40;
        camera.position.z = 40;

        camera.lookAt(scene.position);
        $("#container").append(renderer.domElement);
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
    });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```